Load data from different HTML files with click event on list items
What I want to achieve:

Add an event listener to all hrefs in the list with class="listen".
When user clicks on any list item then replace the content of the div with id="SelectedText" with the content of the chosen file.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Read file into div</title>
  <article>
    <h1>My HTMl</h1>
    <ul class = "listen">
      <li><a class="loc" href="file1.html">Select file 1</a>
      <li><a class="loc" href="file2.htm">Select file 2</a>
      <li><a class="loc" href="file2.txt">Select file 3</a>
      <li><a        href="https://example.com/">Load external file in new window with noopener</a>
    </ul>
    <h1>Please find selected content below:</h1>
    <div id = "SelectedText">
      <p>Replace me
    </div>
    <script> magic here </script>
  </article>

<!-- Local file -->
<p>file i contains for example:
<h1>Ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

I tried:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="loadDoc('/nieuws.htm'); return false;">Nieuws</a>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="loadDoc('/teams/teams.htm'); return false;">Teams</a>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="loadDoc('/links/links.htm'); return false;">Links</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main id="content">
  <p>Replace me
  </main>

with JavaScript function:
    <script>
    // Load external HTML document in div.
    function loadDoc(x) {
      fetch(x)
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.status != 200) { throw new Error("Bad Server Response"); }
        return result.text();
      })
      .then((content) => {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;
      })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
    }
    </script>

But I find a solution with event-handlers more elegant.
Update How to open the file in new window when an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error occurs.

Note: After the catch (err)  I would like to execute the default behaviour, e.g. load the file in a separate window (_blank). No idea how to do this.
Application
Consider a website with choices:

choice - 1
choice - 2
choice - 3
Rest of the page...
....
....

Then if the user select choice 1 I would like to put the text regarding this choice in the rest of the page.
Note
I have a small old website.
My question is about menu management: how can I insert web page content within the main page?
Over time, I have realised that using an iframe is the most obvious solution.

where is this document.getElementById("content") element?

What happened when you tried addEventListener?

<p>Replace me is invalid markup

file1.htm ≠ file1.html

@Roko C.Buljan<p>Replace me  is accepted by the W3C Markup Validation Service.

@Jaromanda X, I have supplemented my (too minimal) example.

@clp you're right, it's optional in specific circumstances.

htm != html. Any errors in console?

@
Roko C. Buljan, No errors or warnings regarding .htm.

Check the example I cooked up for this SO answer

Instead of adding an event listener to all hrefs, why don't you use event delegation?

@AbsoluteBeginner, see my note.

Based on this similar answer on how to fetch partial HTML content from files

use the Fetch API
use addEventListener instead of inline JS like onclick
use event.preventDefault() to prevent the default browser behavior (follow anchors)

Having HTML partials like: page1.html in the root of your project
pageN.html
<h1>This is page N</h1>

this would be your main page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Read file into div</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My HTML</h1>
    <ul class="listen">
        <li><a href="file1.html" class="loc">Load file 1</a>
        <li><a href="file2.html" class="loc">Load file 2</a>
        <li><a href="file3.html" class="loc">Load file 3</a>
    </ul>
    <h1>Please find selected content below:</h1>
    <div id="SelectedText">
        <p>Replace me</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        const loadPartial = async (elAnchor, elTarget) => {
            const file = elAnchor.getAttribute("href");
            try {
                const res = await fetch(file);
                const html = await res.text();
                const domp = new DOMParser();
                const doc = domp.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
                elTarget.innerHTML = ""; // clear old content
                elTarget.append(doc.documentElement);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                open(file, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
            };
        };


        const elTarget = document.querySelector("#SelectedText");
        const elListen = document.querySelector(".listen");

        elListen.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            const elAnchor = evt.target.closest(".loc");
            if (!elAnchor) return;
            evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser following the anchor
            loadPartial(elAnchor, elTarget);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I've used DOMParser for injecting elements into your page as a security measure (XSS Vulnerability). If you trust the content that's being inserted you might instead use this simpler (and faster) solution inside the try block:
const res = await fetch(file);
const html = await res.text();
elTarget.innerHTML = html;

Tip:
developers in need to dynamically (AJAX) populate/fetch partials into their page often forget that, as the page content drastically and meaningfully changes, there's the need for the visitors to navigate back / forward the history, bookmark or share the current page's content direct link. With the above that's impossible, so I would suggest to explore the History API - namely the pushState, popState, and replaceState methods to achieve single-page application routing.

Works very fine indeed. However, how to deal with CORS errors.  I have added an external file to my question.

How to restrict the href`s to anchors with class "loc"?

@clp updated the answer to open a new tab on error using window.open() (you'll also have to move const file out of the try block). Regarding your other question, it's simple as well... add class="loc" to the anchors in HTML and then in JS instead of const elAnchor = evt.target.closest("a"); use const elAnchor = evt.target.closest(".loc");

This requires possibly a separate question. But how to ignore specific errors? For example a parse error in reading a .css file.

@clp exactly, this goes far out of the scope of the question. If you do plan to ask a new one, please be precise in explaining what you're trying to build and the errory you're facing in the process. Perhaps you might be asking for an XY-Problem so do our best.

The errors happen to be of my own making. I have converted my application and found some small differences I do not understand yet. I will work out a minimal example if I still don't.

Y == <a href=file1.html' target='div#my_div'>Read HTML-text into div</a>

I don't understand your last comment (besides being invalid HTML)

I was referring to your XY comment. What I want (=Y)  is a  functionality, but with the difference that the file is not loaded in a _blank page, but in an HTML placeholder, for example div#mydiv.

@clp I've edited the above code several days ago. As you can see it can open an external page inside a new window/tab. See the catch block and open(file, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");

@clp if you only want to load an ID element (from an external or local page) into your page, like I've done in the linked answer - use that answer instead and adapt it with the above click handlers. You might want to extract the fragment identifier: somepage.html#someElemID you might want to retrieve that ID using const [page, id] = file.split("#") and later .append( that doc.documentElement.getElementById(id)

I have updated my question to explain my app,

@clp I'm not sure to understand what you're after with the edit. The code above should work perfectly fine for those exact tasks: 1. insert content into element, 2. open a _blank page if CORS.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your loadDoc function doesn't do anything.
You need to use fetch using x as the url.
fetch(x).then(


My example was too minimal indeed.
