How do I make the friendly content of an iframe seamlessly part of a page, and inherit styles from the parent page?
How to inherit the font styles from the parent of an iframe.
If this is impossible, what could be the alternative?
I maintain a small website. The main menu looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Container for iframe</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #main   { height: 100%; }
    iframe              { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    body, #main         { font-family: sans-serif; }
    #main               { background-color: azure; }
    iframe, #main       { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
  </style>
  
  <!-- Load web page into iframe content. -->
  <p>Container for iframe</p>
  <p><a href="choice-1.html" target="content">Inherit font from iframe</a>
  <p><a href="choice-2.html" target="content">Choice two</a>
  
  <div id="main" style="background-color: azure; color: red">
   <p>Show iframe below:
   <iframe name="content" src="choice-1.html"></iframe>
  </div>
</html>

This is the html of the child page.
In this example, the iframe adopts the background colour of the div it contains. The idea is to import the parent's font:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
  html, body {font-family: inherit;}     */ <------------< */
</style>
  <h1>I am choice one</h1>
  <p>I try to inherit the font from my parent, but failed...
</html>

I am looking for a solution that does not require any knowledge of the pages to be included. I also want the pages to be agnostic about the parent. This makes the overall design more robust and stable.
The problem is that the website should be manageable by someone with limited knowledge of html, css and javascript. A simple solution would be appreciated.

Why don't you load an external "style.css"  in all html files via <link> element? I don't think iframe simplifies anything. A dynamic content replacement via JS is more maintainable (e.g from an object defining all contents or via fetch() )

You can easily replace certain parts of your html e.g with a loaded and parsed chunk of an external html (e.g a cetain atricel or div). The iframe concept also complicates layout as you would need to adjust its height according to the inner content.

@herrstrietzel, I want the pages to be agnostic about the parent. So no explicit reference to the parent domain.

@herrstrietzel, I am looking for a solution that does not require any knowledge of the pages to be included. I have clarified my question.

Then you should stick with the ajax approach as describes in the previous [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79050449/load-data-from-different-html-files-with-click-event-on-list-items) or change the contents from a variable/object provided the separate html pages don't need to be opened in standalone page views

@herrstrietzel, sorry, what do you mean by: "or change the contents from a variable/object provided the syparate html pages don't need to be opened in standalone page views".

If the contents of the loaded html files is rather small and shouldn't be opened separately/directly but only in the main page you could collect all html data in an object. See this codepen example. The main advantage you can add new contents in one place just by adding a new item to the object. Besides you can auto update/synchronize the navigation links with the current list of html contents

Very nice indeed, but not for the faint-hearted.

Iframes do not automatically inherit styles from the parent page. But, you can pass the font style as a parameter in the URL of the iframe.
src="choice-1.html?font=sans-serif"

By sending the font information to the child page this way, the child page can retrieve it from the URL. You can achieve this using a JavaScript feature called URLSearchParams.
Here’s the script you’ll need to add to your child page:
<script>
 const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
 const font = urlParams.get('font');
 if (font) {
     document.body.style.fontFamily = font;
 }
</script>


How to handle more complicated parameters as: font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif, Helvetica Neue?

To handle more complex parameters, you can pass the entire font css stirng via the url, but it must be properly encoded: spaces become %20 and quotes (") becomes %22 and comma (,) becomes %2C... For example, the css you have provided would be encoded into: 1rem/1.5%20sans-serif%2C%20Helvetica%20Neue. When the child page retrieves these parameters, use decodeURIComponent() function to decode the URL. So instead of writing document.body.style.fontFamily = font; you should use  document.body.style.cssText = decodeURIComponent(styles);.
